# Codeigniter : Like query with empty post data

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

i am querying db against posted values through the form using or_like. If none of the posted field is empty below code works

```
        $tbl_name= 'tbl_member_'.$this->session->userdata('userid');
        $this->db->select('name,email,phone');
        $this->db->from($tbl_name);
        $this->db->group_start();
        $this->db->like('name', $this->input->post('name'));
        $this->db->or_like('phone',$this->input->post('phonenumber'));
        $package= $this->input->post('package');
        $this->db->or_like('body_weight', $this->input->post('body_weight'));
        $this->db->group_end();
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return  $query->result());
```

else it prints all the records, please guide me on how can I fix my issue that empty value is ignored, i tried to wrap my query as below in php blocks but it did not work

```
        $tbl_name= 'tbl_member_'.$this->session->userdata('userid');
        $this->db->select('name,email,phone');
        $this->db->from($tbl_name);
        $this->db->group_start();
        if($this->input->post('name') && $this->input->post('name')!='' ){
            $this->db->like('name', $this->input->post('name'));
        }
        if($this->input->post('phonenumber') && $this->input->post('phonenumber')!='' ){
            $this->db->or_like('phone',$this->input->post('phonenumber'));
        }
        if($this->input->post('package') && $this->input->post('package')!='' ){
            $package= $this->input->post('package');
        }
        if($this->input->post('body_weight') && $this->input->post('body_weight')!='' ) {
            $this->db->or_like('body_weight', $this->input->post('body_weight'));
        }
        if($this->input->post('blood_group') && $this->input->post('blood_group')!='' ){
            $this->db->or_like('blood_group',$this->input->post('blood_group'));

        }
        if($this->input->post('gender') && $this->input->post('gender')!='' ){
            $this->db->or_like('gender',$this->input->post('gender'));
        }

        $this->db->group_end();
        $query = $this->db->get();
```

Thanks

**EDIT**

I used below code to sort my problem and it worked perfectly :

```
         if($this->input->post()){
         $form_values= array(
         'name'         =>  $this->input->post('name'),
            'phone'         =>  $this->input->post('phonenumber'),
            'gender'        =>  $this->input->post('gender'),
            'package'       =>  $this->input->post('package'),
            'body_weight'   =>  $this->input->post('body_weight'),
            'blood_group'   => $this->input->post('blood_group'),
        );
        $data['fields']= $form_values;
        $form_values=array_filter($form_values);
        if (!empty($form_values)){
            $tbl_name= 'tbl_member_'.$this->session->userdata('userid');
            $this->db->select('id,name,phone,blood_group,gender,body_weight,package');
            $this->db->from($tbl_name);
            $this->db->like($form_values);
            $data['members'] = $this->db->get()->result();

        }
```

Comment: Do you really have a table for each user?? `$tbl_name= 'tbl_member_'.$this->session->userdata('userid');` Thats a terrible idea. WHat happens awhen you get 1000 users, or 1,000,000 users. Will you really query 1,000,000 tables to search to see is a user exists, or their password is correct

Comment: that is a very particular scenario,  thats why its kept like this , i understand your concern

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```php
$tbl_name= 'tbl_member_'.$this->session->userdata('userid');
$this->db->select('name,email,phone');
$this->db->from($tbl_name);
$this->db->group_start();
if(!empty($this->input->post('name'))){
    $this->db->or_like('name', $this->input->post('name'));
}
if(!empty($this->input->post('phonenumber'))){
    $this->db->or_like('phone',$this->input->post('phonenumber'));
}
if(!empty($this->input->post('package'))){
    $package= $this->input->post('package');
}
if(!empty($this->input->post('body_weight'))) {
    $this->db->or_like('body_weight', $this->input->post('body_weight'));
}
if(!empty($this->input->post('blood_group'))){
    $this->db->or_like('blood_group',$this->input->post('blood_group'));
}
if(!empty($this->input->post('gender'))){
    $this->db->or_like('gender',$this->input->post('gender'));
}
$this->db->group_end();
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.